# Substring results in non-printable characters

Tags: php, substring, non-ascii-characters

As part of inserting product names in a flat file, I have to truncate them to 50 characters at most.

However, some product names contain characters with accents and if these are located at the 50th position (or so), the truncated product name does not display properly.

Here is how to replicate the issue (PHP):

```
$tmp = "Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2015 (Renovación) Suscripción Anual 3 PC";
$xxx = substr(trim($tmp), 0, 50);

echo $tmp . PHP_EOL;
echo $xxx . PHP_EOL;
```

displays:

```
Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2015 (Renovación) Suscripción Anual 3 PC
Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2015 (Renovación) Suscripci�
```

How can I get rid of these undisplayable characters �?

Comment: You chop a multi byte character in two. Not a good idea, that hurts. Use the multi byte variants of php's string functions. See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mb-substr.php) instead of `substr`:

```
$tmp = "Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2015 (Renovación) Suscripción Anual 3 PC";
$xxx = mb_substr(trim($tmp), 0, 50);

echo $tmp . PHP_EOL;
echo $xxx . PHP_EOL;
```

From the docs:

> Performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of
>   characters. Position is counted from the beginning of str. First
>   character's position is 0. Second character position is 1, and so on.